# C# and Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

```
    public List<Client> GetClients()
     {
         List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
         clients.Add(new Client()
         {
            Name = "Name1",
         });
         clients.Add(new Client()
         {
            Name = "Name2",
         });
         return clients;
     }
```

How could I make a xaml in Silverlight contains a textbox=Name and two button: Next and Back. When I click Next the textbox = "Name2" and when I click Back the textbox = "Name1"

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Create XAML as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="txtSelectedName" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="113,110,290,171" />
    <Button Name="btnPrevious" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="46,159,357,122" Content="Previous" Click="btnPrevious_Click" />
    <Button Name="btnNext" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="192,158,211,122" Content="Next" Click="btnNext_Click" />
</Grid>
```

If you want a simple solution write the logic to update TextBlock text code in code behind.

```
    private int _index = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _clients = GetClients();
        txtSelectedName.Text = _clients[_index].Name;

    }
    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _index = _index == 0 ? _clients.Count - 1 : _index - 1;
        txtSelectedName.Text = _clients[_index].Name;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _index = _index == _clients.Count - 1 ? 0 : _index + 1;
        txtSelectedName.Text = _clients[_index].Name;
    }
```

But if its a serious application and there is scope of the application getting complex over time you may want to use MVVM pattern as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="txtSelectedName" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="113,110,290,171" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedName}" />
    <Button Name="btnPrevious" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="46,159,357,122" Content="Previous" Command="{Binding Path=Next}" />
    <Button Name="btnNext" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="192,158,211,122" Content="Next" Command="{Binding Path=Previous}" />
</Grid>
```

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }




public class MainWindowViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private List<Client> _clients;
    private int _index;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _clients = GetClients();
        _index = 0;
        SelectedName = _clients[_index].Name;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public List<Client> GetClients()
    {
        List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
        clients.Add(new Client()
        {
            Name = "Name1",
        });
        clients.Add(new Client()
        {
            Name = "Name2",
        });
        return clients;
    }

    private string _selectedName;
    public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return _selectedName; }
        set
        {
            if(_selectedName != value)
            {
                _selectedName = value;
                OnPropertyChange("SelectedName");
            }
        }
    }


    private RelayCommand _next;
    public RelayCommand Next
    {
        get
        {
            return _next ?? (_next = new RelayCommand(param => this.SetNextName()));
        }
    }

    private void SetNextName()
    {
        _index = _index == _clients.Count - 1 ? 0 : _index + 1;
        SelectedName = _clients[_index].Name;
    }

    private RelayCommand _previous;
    public RelayCommand Previous
    {
        get
        {
            return _previous ?? (_previous = new RelayCommand(param => this.SetPreviousName()));
        }
    }

    private void SetPreviousName()
    {
        _index = _index == 0 ? _clients.Count - 1 : _index - 1;
        SelectedName = _clients[_index].Name;
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Predicate<object> _canexecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null){}

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canexecute = canExecute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canexecute == null || _canexecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;}
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you set the text of textbox on click event of the buttons. So XAML will be like this.

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,144,0,0" Name="txtMain" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188"  />
            <Button Content="Back" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,238,0,0" Name="btnBack" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnBack_Click" />
            <Button Content="Next" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,238,286,0" Name="btnNext" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnNext_Click" />
```

When page is initialized then you need to add text to textbox so the initialization code goes here.

```
public List<Client> _clients = new List<Client>();
        private int _index = 0;

    public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                this.loginContainer.Child = new LoginStatus();
                this._clients = GetClients();
                if(_index<this._clients.Count)
                txtMain.Text = this._clients[_index].Name;
            }
```

and then you need to have logic in click events like this.

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._index -= 1;

        if (_index >= 0)
            txtMain.Text = this._clients[_index].Name;
        else
            this._index += 1;

    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._index += 1;

        if (_index < this._clients.Count)
            txtMain.Text = this._clients[_index].Name;
        else
            this._index -= 1;
    }
```

Comment: It works fine if you know the name. But what happen if you do not know the name? What I want is: First time the xaml is load the textbox will contains the first record, wich is "Name1". When you click the Nextbutton the second record is appear, which is "Name2" and so on if you have more than 2 records...